# What is Metadata in SQLalchemy diagram generation?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have created a tables in alchemy, and want to create the database diagram for it. I saw some suggestions based on this, but I don't know what is Metadata.

My tables structure in the

```
Base(DeclarativeBase): graph = create_schema_graph(metadata=MetaData('postgres://user:pwd@host/database'),    show_datatypes=False,

//The image would get nasty big if we'd show the datatypes    show_indexes=False, # ditto for indexes    rankdir='LR', # From left to right (instead of top to bottom)    concentrate=False # Don't try to join the relation lines together ) graph.write_png('dbschema.png')
```

Comment: The `MetaData` class here does not seem to be SQLAlchemy's [MetaData class](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData), so without more details about this code I don't think this question can be answered.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.